# onPlayerStateChange YouTube API doesn't work

Tags: api, youtube

The following [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) doesn't work. How do I fix this problem?

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
    // Create YouTube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // Autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // When video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if(event.data === 0) {
            alert('done');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have suddenly stopped getting callbacks for onPlayerStateChange as well (started last night).

I found a [Google+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google+) post, *[Youtube is experiencing issues with its Player API. Things should be solved "very soon". Other videos work. Sorry for the inconvenience.](https://plus.google.com/112441181479806615038/posts/cx8z4PLkN4N)*, claiming YouTube is experiencing an issue with their player [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), but I haven't seen anything from YouTube confirming this as of yet. I guess I will sit tight.

Update: Looks like they have confirmed they are having a temporary issue with the iframe API: *[Issue 4706: iframe API: onStateChange not firing](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4706)*